# How to create Firestore subcollection using the new WebSDK 9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Basically all I want to do is create a subcollection in my document, but using the webSDK 9, the tree-shakable SDK.

I've found solutions, but all of them are outdated and use the old sdk.

If this helps, I'm using NextJS and ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `DocumentReference` of the Firestore doc to which you want to add a subcollection, as follows:

```
const docRef = ....;
const docSubcollectionRef = collection(docRef, 'theSubColl');
await addDoc(docSubcollectionRef, {foo: 'bar'});
```

---

More concretely, if you have a doc in the `theTempoColl` collection with id `doc1` (i.e. `docRef = doc(db, 'theTempoColl', 'doc1')`), the above code will generate a document with the following path: `theTempoColl/doc1/theSubColl/{auto_generated_Id}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use also setDoc if you define specific document id.

```
import {db} from './config';
import {setDoc, doc } from '@firebase/firestore'

export default function Page(){
 const createDocWithSpecificId = async () => {
  cosnt docRef = doc(db, 'collection_name', 'specific_id');
  const createDoc = await setDoc(docRef, {foo : 'bar'});
 };
}
```

Thank you.